# Can I set up a timer for retrieving messages from Backend server?

Tags: ios, parsing, timer

I have an app that uses timers in conjunction with the UIImagePicker and sends the images to Parse. I am trying to find out the best way to go about setting my timers up. What I need is to be able to have the images uploaded to Parse but not be released to the recipients until a date/time specified by the user uploading the images. I need the images to still be released to the recipients even if the app is not open or the users phone is off/broken. Is there a way I can do this from a backend server like Parse or is there a way to set it up within the app itself so that the timer will still go off when the app isn't loaded? (New to development and just looking for the best way to achieve this) thanks!

Comment: This is something that would have to run on the server. You may be able to do this using Parse's Cloud Code, but I'm not familiar enough with that API to give you specifics.

Comment: that's kind of what I thought. Thanks! I'll look into their Cloud services and see what I can find out.